# Is this generalization of CRT true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$a^n \equiv b_1 \bmod p_1$

$a^n \equiv b_2 \bmod p_2$

if $gcd(b_1,p_2) = gcd(b_2,p_1) = 1$ then $a^n \equiv b_1 \cdot b_2 \bmod p_1\cdot p_2$

$p_1$ and $p_2$ are not necessarily coprime.

**edit**

what about $gcd(p_1, p_2) = 1$ ?

Comment: $a=5$, $n=1$, $b_1=2$, $p_1=3$, $b_2=3$, $p_2=2$, but $a^n=5\not\equiv 6=b_1b_2\pmod{p_1p_2=6}$.

Comment: To create a subscript, use the underscore.  Now `p_2` becomes $p_2$.

Comment: Same example as above.

Comment: @nextpuzzle thanks

Comment: Note that you do **not** solve [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) simultaneous equivalences by multiplication, in general.